# Deactivating 'animations' in phpmyadmin 4.x?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've just upgraded to phpmyadmin 4.x (coming from 3.x). Starting with this version phpmyadmin becomes really slow in UI related things (I use Firefox on linux). 
As I want to have a quick and usable admin tool and no award winning UI, I just want to disable all the neat ui things like automated scrolling and such. Is there a way to just have a clean and *fast* ui with 4.x like I had in 3.x without downgrading?
Btw: I already using the 'original' theme.

Thanks and regards
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the sliders, try this:
cfg['InitialSlidersState'] = 'disabled';

About the rest, please give more details about what you want to disable.

Also, the latest stable version is 4.0.5, with 4.0.6 being released soon.